# Dart Stream.periodic memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, stream, lifecycle, angular-dart

I have the following code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'my-screen',
  directives: [coreDirectives, ],
  templateUrl: 'my_component.html',
)
class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  Stream periodicStream;
  StreamSubscription periodicSubs;
  MyBloc myBloc;

  myComponent(this.myBloc) : super() {
    myBloc.listen((newState){
      if (newState is SomeBlocState) {
        periodicStream = new Stream.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1));
        periodicSubs = periodicStream.listen(this.onTick);
      }
    });
  }

  void onTick(dynamic) {
    print('onTick');
  }

  @override
  void ngOnInit() {
  }

  @override
  void ngOnDestroy() {
    print('ngOnDestroy');
    if (periodicSubs != null) {
      print('periodicSubs.cancel()');
      periodicSubs.cancel();
      periodicSubs = null;
      periodicStream = null;
    }
  }
}
```

The main issue is:

1) when component is created for the first time everything seems ok, I have console 'onTick' messages and after component destroyed (ngOnDestroy called) this messages are disappeared

2) but when component is created for the second time (and so on) and periodic stream initialised again, I end up with double 'onTick' console log messages, which seems like previous stream is steel alive

What can cause such behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was in BLoC listen callback invocation. When component tries to listen BLoC seconds time, callback is invoked immediately to report current state.